# Разделение файла на строки и структурирование файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

начал изучать работу с файлами в Python. С загрузкой данных в файл и чтением из файла, я разобрался, а вот как можно поменять, в файле, строчки местами?
для наглядности, пример, как выгружается, и как должно получиться:

```
***** ^Type=5^ ^Acc=3^ - Запрос выписки по валютному счету за день
^DocDate=03.03.2022^
^Num=F5Z^
^Opr=1^
^UNNKorr=673^
^Nazn=mLAKOKRASOcNYi CEm 
^Nazn2=^
^I2=RUB^
^DebQ=0.00^
^CreQ=1000000.00^
^Deb=0.00^
^Cre=29855.00^

^DocDate=03.03.2022^
^Num=0219^
^Opr=1^
^Nazn=КОНВЕРСИЯ ИНОСТРАННОЙ ВАЛЮТЫ СОГЛАСНО ДОГОВОРА НА ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЕ ПО ВАЛЮТНО-ОБМЕННЫМ 
ОПЕРАЦИЯМ.^
^Nazn2=^
^I2=RUB^
^DebQ=993225.00^
^CreQ=0.00^
^Deb=29652.73^
^Cre=0.00^
```

нужно поменять строки местами так, что бы получилось:

```
***** ^Type=5^ ^Acc=3^ - Запрос выписки по валютному счету за день
^DocDate=03.03.2022^
^Num=F5Z^
^Opr=1^
^Deb=0.00^
^DebQ=0.00^
^Cre=29855.00^
^CreQ=29855.00^
^I2=RUB^
^UNNKorr=673^
^Nazn=mLAKOKRASOcNYi CENm 
^Nazn2=^

^DocDate=03.03.2022^
^Num=0219^
^Opr=1^
^Deb=29652.73^
^DebQ=29652.73^
^Cre=0.00^
^CreQ=0.00^
^I2=RUB^
^Nazn=КОНВЕРСИЯ ИНОСТРАННОЙ ВАЛЮТЫ СОГЛАСНО ДОГОВОРА НА ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЕ ПО ВАЛЮТНО-ОБМЕННЫМ 
ОПЕРАЦИЯМ.^
^Nazn2=^
```

но таких блоков не обязательно два, это только пример

Comment: читаете из одного файла, записываете в другой, по завершении старый файл удаляете. при необходимости переименовываете файл (до или после).

Comment: пробовал так, что бы понять, что за строка, проверял по первым символам строки:
    for i_lines2 in openFile:

    if i_lines2[0:8] == '^DocDate':
        docDate = i_lines2
        sym_count2 += docDate
но таких строк в файле несколько, и в новый файл он записывает сразу все совпадения

Comment: регулярку пробуйте

Comment: я бы для начала разбил бы на блоки,  а потом каждый блок на строки. Искал бы "^Nazn="

Comment: @СергейШашко спасибо, сейчас буду смотреть, что такое регулярка и как ей пользоваться)